# iostream file not found

Tags: c++, iostream

I have just started to learn Object Oriented at C++.
In my first lesson I received that error **"iostream file not found"**.
I use Fedora 24 and atom editor for coding.
For build I use that command `g++ main.cpp -o a` I also installed atom's plugin

```
gpp-compiler
```

My main file is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "BMI.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
        string name;
        int height;
        double weight;

        cout << "Enter your name: ";
        cin >> name;

        cout << "Enter your height (in inches): ";
        cin >> height;

        cout << "Enter your weight: ";
        cin >> weight;
        BMI a;
        //  BMI Student_1(name, height, weight);

        return 0;
}
```

when I run main file without BMI object it works.
But when I added BMI object in the main function the output is the error.

My BMI object:
Header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef BMI_H
#define BMI_H

class BMI {
public:
//Default Constructor
        BMI();
//Overload Constructor
        BMI(string, int, double);
private:
//Member Variable
        string newName;
        int newHeight;
        double newWeight;
};


#endif
```

CPP file:

```
#include "BMI.h"

BMI::BMI(){
  newName = "aa";
  newHeight = 0;
  newHeight = 0.0;
}

BMI::BMI(string name, int height, double weight){
  newName = name;
  newHeight = height;
  newWeight = weight;
}
```

This tutorial from 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vz1O9nRyZaY

The question is why doesn't it work and why it works without BMI object?

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: How are you building your program?

Comment: Arguably the best way to learn is to read books. Here is a nice list of [C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: g++ main.cpp -o a the output is /tmp/ccM9rMj9.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `BMI::BMI()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @MichaelHorojanski You are serious? add your BMI.cpp file!

Comment: Have you tried "g++ main.cpp BMI.cpp -o a"?

Comment: Yes, it works thanks a lot..!

Comment: Raw N, yeah I know.

Answer (score 1):

You have typing error in your cpp file :

```
newHeight = 0;
newHeight = 0.0; // <- error
```

try :

```
newHeight = 0;
newWeight = 0.0;
```